# How to log in to Craigslist using C#

Tags: c#, craigslist

I'm using the following code to log into [Craigslist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craigslist), but haven't succeeded yet.

```
string formParams = string.Format("inputEmailHandle={0}&inputPassword={1}", "must_chd@yahoo.com", "removed");
//string postData = "inputEmailHandle=must_chd@yahoo.com&inputPassword=removed";
string uri = "https://accounts.craigslist.org/";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Method = "POST";
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
cookyHeader = response.Headers["Set-cookie"];

string pageSource;
string getUrl = "https://post.craigslist.org/del";
WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookyHeader);
WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: i have just "false" the "AllowAutoRedirect" and it start working. something great.... 

request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

Answer (score 1):

Use WebTest to record your login process, then generate the code. This will help you to understand what is wrong with YOUR code.